# Confused about default behavior of model initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following...

Model:

```
class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller:

```
class EquipmentController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_equipment, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /equipment/new
  def new
    @equipment = Equipment.new
  end


  # POST /equipment or /equipment.json
  def create
    @equipment = Equipment.new(equipment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @equipment.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@equipment.user, @equipment], notice: "Equipment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @equipment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @equipment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Test:

```
class EquipmentControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @equipment = equipment(:one)
    sign_in_as(@equipment.user)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_user_equipment_url(@equipment.user.id)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

My test fails here, because `equipment.user` is null.

```
<%= form_with(model: [equipment.user, equipment]) do |form| %>
```

However, when I visit the corresponding URL in the development environment in the browser, it works. Debugging the development environment, the `Equipment.new` sets the user on the new equipment object. However, when running the test, the user is not set.

Making this change in the controller fixes the issue, **but I don't understand the difference in behavior between the integration test and using the browser**. Can someone explain?

```
@equipment = Equipment.new user: Current.user
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why `@equipment = Equipment.new user: Current.user` doesn't cause a missing constant error. Don't you mean to call a `current_user` method?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a lot less confusing if you wrote the test properly:

```ruby
class EquipmentControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)
    sign_in_as(@user)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_user_equipment_url(@user)
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

You should not use the `equipment` fixture when you're testing the new/create action - after all what your test is supposed to cover is the form for a completely new resource. The `equipment` fixture would be used when showing and updating an existing equipment.

Then I think you're falling for a classic  trap and confusing the `@equipment` instance variable in your test and the instance variable in your controller with the same name.

Remember that your test and the controller are completely separate instances of different classes - sometimes even running in a completely different processes. Data doesn't just magically teleport itself from the test to the controller - it has to be passed through parameters or be loaded from the database.

`@equipment` in your controller is just a new Equipment instance that you have created there which doesn't have a user assigned. Thats why you need to assign the user.

Note that unless your users need to be able to create equipment for other users you don't actually need to have a nested route like this. You could just use `GET /equipment/new` and fetch the user from the session (or a token) instead of a parameter.

For example given a typical Devise setup you would do:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :equipment
end
```

```
class EquipmentController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_equipment, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user! # ensure that a user is logged in.

  # POST /equipment or /equipment.json
  def create
    @equipment = current_user.equipment.new(equipment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @equipment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @equipment, notice: "Equipment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @equipment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @equipment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```